# Business/services reviews site for Colombia

Tags: online-resources, colombia, reviews

Is there a Yelp equivalent for Colombia? The best I found was CiudadGuru, but that seems to be more of a Yellow Pages (business listings) than a reviews/ratings site. I'm looking for services like barber shops, which are not covered by TripAdvisor or Degusta.

Google Maps has some reviews but they're mostly limited to a 1-2 phrases or simply empty, just a star rating. Same for Foursquare - 1-sentence reviews.